# How to display a list of features, in the WiX based installer, that are going to be installed?

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I want to display a list of features that are going to be installed in the windows installer. This list will appear just before the user is about to install the product. I would like to know if there is a standard way to do this using WiX?

I tried to create a separate UI dialog just before the Verify Ready dialog which has a text control. The intention here is to display a text if a feature is being installed and hide that text if it is not being installed.

```
<Control Id="FeatureText" Type="Text" Text="SomeText">
      <Condition Action="show">
        <![CDATA[(&feature="3")]]>
      </Condition>
      <Condition Action="hide">
        <![CDATA[(&feature="2")]]>
      </Condition>
</Control>
```

the problem with this code is that the Action specified in the condition is not being performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying out a number of things I found that:

i- There is no need for quotes around the numbers and

ii- The controls can be set to hidden by default.

The following code is now working for me

```
<Control Id="FeatureText" Type="Text" Text="SomeText" Hidden="yes">
  <Condition Action="show">
    <![CDATA[(&feature=3)]]>
  </Condition>
</Control>
```

but what I still don't know is, if this is the best/right way to do what I intend to do...